# How to create an effect to highlight correct answer

Tags: swift, xcode, button, highlight

I am learning Swift, and I am throwing myself in the deep end to force myself to learn the language. I have a nephew who is a baby and thought to make an app to help him learn numbers.

The app is designed to set a set number of buttons on the screen like the one provided below. I have the code to play Directions, which tells the user which number to select. A-N14a, the audio file, says to click the 4. The Done button is set to move to the next screen.

What I am asking is that if I want 4 to be pressed, and they press the 9, I want to know how to implement a feature to give a hint to click the number 4? The idea is to change the background to a button, but I don't know how to implement the feature. I am also open to other ideas. As a note, I do not know what to do, and I'm trying to learn, so the code provided is probably very simplistic and is at the beginning stages.

Below is an image of the screen and the code for that page.

[ScreenShot of Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1lDm.png)

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Intervention_Numerals1: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var Directions: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Done: UIButton!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpElements()
        //Audio Test
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "A-N14a", ofType:"mp3")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func setUpElements() {
        // Style the elements
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(Directions)
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(Done)
    }

    @IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    
    
}
```

Please let me know any tips or advice or links to similar questions, even though I could not find any on my own.

Comment: The code you have posted does not seem to have **anything** to do with the question you have asked. Shouldn't you post the code the generates the number buttons, along with the IBActions that are triggered when the buttons are tapped? And shouldn't you explain what you mean by "Directions?" Does the app have pre-recorded sounds that tell you nephew which number to tap or something?

Comment: The code I have doesn't have any attempts at what to do because I was genuinely lost at what to do. As for the other comments, I have edited my post to be more clear; I was not aware that it was confusing, and I genuinely apologize for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Record the sound "Tap the number" and then the sounds for the numbers 0 through 9. Name the number sounds "0.mp3" through "9.mp3"

Create a storyboard with 4 buttons on it (like the picture you posted.)

Set up button IBOutlets `buttonA` - `buttonD`. Put those buttons into an array:

```
let buttonsArray = [buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD]
```

Fill an array with the numbers 0-9. Shuffle it. Remove 4 values put them into an array "buttonValues" (use the method `removeLast()`.) The code to generate non-repeating values from 0-9 might look like this:

```
var randomNumbers =  [Int]() //Define an array to hold random Ints
var lastValueReturned: Int?

//Function to return a random Int. It won't return the same value twice
func randomNumber() -> Int {


    //Remove and return an item from the array
    var result: Int
    repeat {
        //If the array is empty, fill it with the shuffled numbers 0...9
        if randomNumbers.isEmpty {
            randomNumbers += Array(0...9).shuffled()
        }
        result = randomNumbers.removeLast()
    } while result == lastValueReturned
    lastValueReturned = result
    return result
}
```

Loop through your array of buttonValues and install the string for each number as the title of one of your buttons:

for index = 0...3 {
buttonsArray[index].setTitle("(buttonValues[index])", forSate: .normal)
}

Pick an index 0-3 to be the "correct" number.

```
let indexToPick = Int.random(in: 0...3)
```

Look up that value in buttonValues, and use it to pick a sound file to play:

```
let numberToPick = buttonValues[indexToPick]

let soundName = "\(numberToPick).mp3"
```

Load and play the "tap the number" sound, and then Load and play the sound for the selected number (`soundName`).

When the user taps a button, have the IBAction method use the sender parameter that is passed to it, and look in the array of buttons, `buttonsArray`, to see which button index was tapped.

If it is the correct button, take the success action.

If the tapped button index is not `indexToPick`, do an animation that changes the background color of the button at `indexToPick`, or the button's border width, or something, and then animates it back to normal. (Look at the UIView `animate(duration:)` family of methods for how to animate the button's background color. Use the form that takes an `options:` parameter, and set the `.autoreverse` option.)

If you're a newbie to iOS development, figuring out how to animate your correct answer button could be a challenge. I created a sample project that just animates one of 4 random buttons: https://github.com/DuncanMC/ButtonAnimation.git

The code for that project is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonD: UIButton!

    //Define an empty array to hold buttons.
    var buttonsArray = [UIButton]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Put our button outlets into an array so we can reference them by index.
        buttonsArray = [buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD]

        //Give our buttons a cornerRadius so they look rounded when we add a border and fill color
        for button in buttonsArray {
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        }
    }

    @IBAction func handleAnimateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isEnabled = false

        //Pick a random button
        let button = buttonsArray.randomElement()!

        //Create an auto-reversing animation that fills the button with cyan, and draws a border around it.
        //(Showing the border won't fade in and out, but it doesn't really matter)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut],
                       animations: {
                        button.backgroundColor = .cyan
                        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                       }, completion: {
                        success in
                        button.backgroundColor = .clear
                        sender.isEnabled = true
                        button.layer.borderWidth = 0
                       })
    }
}
```

Comment: See the animation code at the end of my answer. You might even want to download the sample project and try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. The sample project was perfect because I could actually see what the code does. I edited my question so that it says that the A-N14a audio says to select the number 4. How would I set the code you wrote to be set to do it only for a select button?

Comment: Edit- I changed buttonsArray.randomElement()! to be buttonA, and it only animates buttonA; I don't know if you will see this but, if you do, please let me know if this is the correct way to do it or if there is another way? I also want to learn how to code correctly and not brute force my way through everything.

Comment: I would suggest pulling out the animation code into a function `animateButton(atIndex:)` Pass it the index of the button you want to animate. At first, call it with a constant index. Later, when you update the app to tell your nephew to press a variety of buttons, your function will support that without changes.

Comment: Take a look at the first part of my answer. I outline a fairly complete approach to developing an app that would really select random numbers and teach somebody to identify their numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows:

**1. Create as many IBOutlets as your numbers (I suppose 0-9 for your example?) and link them to your buttons - E.g.**

```
@IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!

// Create as many as you need - Probably 10?
```

**2. Create an IBAction and link it to all your buttons, with this code**

```
@IBAction func checkCorrectAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
   let arrayOfButtons:[UIButton] = [Button1, Button2] // Here you add all your buttons

   let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal)!

   if buttonTitle == "YOUR CORRECT ANSWER" {   //You have to substitute "YOUR CORRECT ANSWER" with the right string value

      sender.backgroundColor = .green

   } else {

      sender.backgroundColor = .red

      for i in arrayOfButtons {

         if i.titleLabel?.text == "YOUR CORRECT ANSWER" { i.backgroundColor = .orange }

      }

   }

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It's just a try btw - Because as commented above your code is not reflecting your question. Happy to help more if I can anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is basically what I was looking for. I do have a question when I do "sender.backgroundColor = .red." I want the sender to be whatever button the user selected automatically. How do I retrieve that information? Also in the line "if i.titleLabel?.text == "YOUR CORRECT ANSWER" { i.backgroundColor = .orange }", what is "titleLabel?", is it the name of the correct button?

Comment: If you link all your buttons to the IBAction (I mean, all of them linked to the same IBAction), "sender" is a parameter that represents the button you are pressing. So, it is what the user selects automatically. titleLabel is an attribute of a button which carries the text which is written on the button. I was imagining this as a sort of calculator, where you have a label on each button saying "1", "2", "3", ..